# Yank context from :g to register VIM

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to use `:g/pattern/z#.5 y P` to yank context from a large file so I can find out why there are duplicates.

`:g/pattern/z#.5` displays fine in interactive mode but `:g/pattern/z#.5 y P` won't yank to the register.

I can do this but would prefer to yank either to a register or another buffer

```
:silent! redir! > file
:g/pattern/z#.5
:redir end
:sp file
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `:g/pattern/z#.5| y P`

Comment: Dammit so easy. Thanks muchly

Comment: You can use `:redir @a>` to redirect messages to the `a` register. Please see `:h :redir`

Comment: Oooh Peter Rincker. If you and FDinoff combine them as an answer I'll accept it and upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the printing (via `:#`) and yanking are two different commands, you have to join them with the *command separator* `|`:

```
:g/pattern/z#.5 | y P
```

Alternatively, you can `:redir` to a register via `@p` (instead of `> file`).